# Stop redirecting to sessions/new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use `before_filter :login_required` on a controller, and everything behaves as it should - a user who isn't logged in is bumped to sessions/new. But given that I'm doing this on the root  url, I'd like to avoid having an actual redirect (to not show /sessions/new) in the user's browser bar. How would I tweak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find where your login_required method is defined, and change the redirect_to location in there to be `redirect_to root_path`.

If you are using restful_authentication, I believe the login_required method is defined in /lib/authenticated_system.rb